# My local repo embeds within itself and creates a sub-directory when pushed to a newly created remote repo

Tags: git, github

Whenever I connect to and push my existing local repo to my newly created remote repo with -

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/greevesh/formosadict.git
git push -u origin main
```

my project is made to be a sub-directory within it's own directory.

Directory link - https://github.com/greevesh/formosadict
Sub-directory link - https://github.com/greevesh/formosadict/tree/main/formosadict

This is not the case with an older project of mine -

https://github.com/greevesh/videogame_store

It takes you straight to root of the project from the directory.

Has anything changed with Git/GitHub recently to make this the case?

Comment: Use `pwd` to check the directory structure, it's possible that you're working under the parent repo

Comment: When you created the repository locally you ran `git init` in the wrong upper directory. The way to fix depends on if you want to preserve the history; if you don't — remove (make backup) `formosadict/.git`, `cd formosadict/formosadict && git init`

Comment: @KassianSun The directory structure looks fine - ```/c/Users/Harri/Desktop/dev-projects/apps/formosadict```.

Comment: @phd Correct. I've resolved the issue following the instructions you provided. Thank you!